# sqlite change SELECT to DELETE

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this SELECT query that returns two rows. How do I delete these rows from the table?

```
%%sql
WITH temp(A, B) as (
    SELECT e0.A, e0.B
    FROM edges e0, edges e1, edges e2
    WHERE e0.B = e1.A
    AND e1.B = e2.A
    AND e2.B= e0.A
    LIMIT 1
)
SELECT s1.*
FROM edges s1
JOIN temp ON
(s1.A = temp.A AND s1.B = temp.B)
OR (s1.A = temp.B AND s1.B = temp.A);
```

The SELECT returns the desired rows to delete. I thought the way to do this was to change the `SELECT s1.*` to `DELETE s1`, but that didn't work

Comment: JUst do   Delete From edges S1 ...

Comment: That does not work. I get (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "s1": syntax error

Comment: Yes, I corrected it

Answer (score 0):

Just do Delete From edges S1

```
WITH temp(A, B) as (
    SELECT e0.A, e0.B
    FROM edges e0, edges e1, edges e2
    WHERE e0.B = e1.A
    AND e1.B = e2.A
    AND e2.B= e0.A
    LIMIT 1
)
Delete
FROM edges 
where exists
(select 1 from temp where
(edges.A = temp.A AND edges.B = temp.B)
OR (edges.A = temp.B AND edges.B = temp.A));
```

Comment: That does not work. I get `(sqlite3.OperationalError) near "s1": syntax error`